Avoid the space given by parskip if it goes on a new page
So, all along the code of my thesis I put blank lines between every mathematical environment, so it starts a new paragraph every time there is an equation. I did it because, since I'm using the package parskip with the \noindent option, I quite like the space it leaves between the text and the equations and there is no other visible effect. The only problem is that if an equation ends being at the start of a new page, it leaves more blank space at the beginning compared to the usual one. Is there a way to impose globally not to leave the space given by the new paragraph if this starts on a new page?

What you doing is actually against recommended general practice, that display math are part of the paragraph text and you should not leave a blank line above it or below it.  I am not too what distribution you have (year), but try  \usepackage{parskip}[=v1] to see if it goes away. But best to post a full MWE for others to reproduce the issue. A new page starts with topskip so that TeX can adjust the depth of the first line.

you have shown no code but \parskip is always ignored at the start of a new page, from your description and mention of using \noindent it would seem you have input errors in your tex markup but it is hard to guess exactly what you have done wrong.

you should never have a blank line before a displayed equation.

Displayed equations should never appear at the start of a page. Your TeX coding is at fault: a math display should never be preceded by a blank line (in the code) and it can be followed by one, but only if the text starts a new paragraph.

There are two ways of achieving your goal regarding the generous amount of whitespace you prefer to see between a text paragraph and a subsequent displayed equation: Your current way -- which, as you've discovered, has a rather unpleasant side effect -- and a better way. The latter consists of not creating the problematic blank lines to begin with and, instead, increasing the values of the length parameters \abovedisplayskip and \abovedisplayshortskip. If you're guessing that these parameters govern the amount of whitespace that's inserted between a paragraph of text and a displayed equation, you would be right.
Since you've provided no relevant LaTeX code to work with -- e.g., Which document class is in use? Is the document class option fleqn set? Is something like onehalfspacing or [shudder] doublespacing in effect? -- I can only provide a generic suggestion: You should insert the instructions
\addtolength{\abovedisplayskip}{1\baselineskip}
\addtolength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{1\baselineskip}

immediately after \begin{document}.
These instructions may need to be tweaked depending on the specifics of your document setup.
